# javascript alternatives to setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I know that would be a duplicate, but I can't find what I need. I try to make a real time mmorpg (refferences:travian,tribal-wars,ikariam,etc) in order to get some experience and still have some fun (my childhood dream).
User have more then one city and he can access each one using a '**select form**'.
When user changes the **select form,** an ajax is going to DB and returns '**current city resources: wood,iron,stone**' also the '**current production**' for each one. All works well. When I change the select form, ajax is updating **resources bar** with a loop over **values class**. I will update my DB stocks table with the current values + productions each hour(would be a waste to make it every 10 seconds). The problem is that I want to run a script every 5-10 seconds which should update client side **resources stock** something like this: "document.getElemByID(wood).html = current dbStocked **wood**(//which has been query once with ajax) + (wood_production/3600(//seconds in a minute)*((current_minutes*60)+(current_seconds)))". All works fine, but when I change the city with select form, setInterval keep running, now having 2 values of **wood** and **wood_prod** in script logic, now on each itineration toogle between this 2 cases. Every 5 seconds the div representing wood value gets:one time last selected city calculation, one time current city calculation. So the div content is juggling each 5 second(interval time). EDIT: The setInterval is kidnaping the value of which one started and not gonna drop it away even replaced by another, so it forces initial values and toogling them with the current ones, every 5 seconds.
Here is a part of my code:

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $("#setCitty").on("change", getstats);
  }
);


function getstats() {
  var city = $('#setCitty').val(); //the select form triggering the ajax
  var identifier = $('#identifier').val(); //don t mind it
  $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'handle/php/cityStatsGet.php',
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        city: city,
        identifier: identifier,
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response.citystats);
        console.log(response.production); //Added console log here...all seems ok, changing city is changing the content of  response.citystats and response.production ..
        clearInterval(interval);
        var v = 0;
        $(".values").each(function() { //i have a mess here, i will use vanilla for performanece later
          $(this).html(response.citystats[v]);
          v++;
        });
        incoming();
        setInterval(incoming, 5000);

        function incoming() {
          var d = new Date();
          var m = d.getMinutes();
          var s = d.getSeconds(); //response.citystats[19] is iron stock
          $('#ironInc').html(parseInt(parseInt(response.citystats[19]) + ((parseInt(response.production[2]) / 3600)) * ((+parseInt(m) * 60) + parseInt(s))));
        } //i parseint all because i have a headpain trying to figure out what is wrong just because js treats pure numbers as strings
      });

  }
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="values" id="ironInc"></span>
```

So...my question is...if I can in some way restart the execution of setInterval (because is not restarting when I recall its patern function). 
EDIT: also, I have in php

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM city_stats WHERE user = ? AND city = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $city);  
$stmt->execute();   
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
//here are some math to get final values eg.:$income = $row['foo']+$row['bar'];
$data = array();

$data['citystats'] = array(
$population,$workers,$houses,$happiness,$popularity,$filantropy,$terror,$tax,
$foodFactor,$innFactor,$religion,$crime,$crowding,$rats,$food,$meat,$fruits,
$chease,$bread,$kiron,$kstone,$kgold,$kwood
     ); //23 ELEMENTs I<23
$data['production'] = array(
    $goldincome,$pwood,$piron,$pstone
);
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
        echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: `clearInterval()` on a `var` you need to assign your `setInterval()` to , then `setInterval()` again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setInterval(..) returns an id for the timer. Call clearInterval(id) when you change cities.

i.E.

```
var id = setInterval(..);
```

And when changing city

```
clearInterval(id);
```

This stops the periodic refresh of wood etc from the previously selected city

Comment: Okay, have a good night mate. If you need further help just write me

Comment: not worked, but I declared as global, now work perfect; I used   clearInterval(window.idul);
window.idul = setInterval(incoming,2000);. Is there any issue using in that method? I mean...performance...or something else?

Comment: Afaik, no. Polluting global namespace isnt optimal, but performance-wise it doesnt matter

Answer (score 2):

You could use `async` functions and work with `promises`:

```js
function sleepPromise(ms)
{
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function sleep()
{
    while(true)
    {
        // do something
        await sleepPromise(2000);   // Sleep desired amount of miliseconds
        // break if needed
        console.log('I have awakend.');
    }
}

sleep();
```

**EDIT:** Here is an example of a valid PHP file structure returning JSON after doing a MySQLi query:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect(...    //Your connection info

    // Your query
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name, price FROM ...");

    // If there are results
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $resultArray = array();

        // Go through them row by row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            // Make the associative array for each row
            $arr = array ('name'=>$row[0],'price'=>$row[1]);
            // Add the row to a list of rows
            array_push($resultArray,$arr);
        }
        // set headers for JSON and json_encode the result array
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($resultArray);
    }
    else echo 'error'
?>
```

**EDIT 2:** Here is your `javascript` code written with `promises`. See if this works for you:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#setCitty").on("change", getstats); 
};

// Returns promise
function goToSleep(miliseconds)
{
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, miliseconds));
}

// Your tasks
function incoming(response)
{
    var d = new Date();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    $('#ironInc').html(parseInt(parseInt(response.citystats[19])+((parseInt(response.production[2])/3600))*((+parseInt(m)*60)+parseInt(s))));
}

// function to handle events
async function handleEvents(city, response)
{
    while(city == $("#setCitty option:selected").val())
    {
        incoming(city, response);  // call function to do stuff
        await goToSleep(1000*5);         // 5 seconds
    }
}


function getstats()
{
    var city = $("#setCitty option:selected").val(); // current selected item
    var identifier = $('#identifier').val();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'post',
        url: 'handle/php/cityStatsGet.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
        city: city,
        identifier: identifier,
    },
    success: function (response)
    {
        handleEvents(city, response);
    });
}
```

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL for example? I will add an example of a PHP file that returns valid JSON using MySQL. Just so we are sure you are getting proper data back.

Comment: no, i query once...Now have 2 arrays return: result.citystats and return.production. Logged them: too long to post it here, All seems ok...

Comment: @BoteaFlorin Can you please edit your question to add the response (print the response from jQuery) so I can see what kind of structure it is returning. It will be easier to fix that way.

Comment: Yeah, that would be best. If it's too big you don't need to post all of it only the section where you are querying and returning results.

Comment: check my edit pls. I added some console logs....I don t know how, but clearInterval is not working because can t find any interval...

Comment: @BoteaFlorin I have included an example of using your `javascript` code with `promises`. I cleaned it up a bit. Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I solved it using clearInterval(window.idul); window.idul = setInterval(incoming,2000);. Is there any problem using it as global? now work fine

Comment: Nope. It's perfectly fine. Though you might want to check my answer under `EDIT2`, it simplifies your problem, and in my opinion `promises` are a better way to go. The `while` in the `handleEvents()` function checks if the `city` is the same as the `current selected city` and if it is not it terminates. The change in city triggers a new `ajax call` that calls `handleEvents()` and so on.

Comment: @BoteaFlorin Glad you got it set up. If you want to use the javascript I wrote and have any problems with the `promises` ping me, though it should work perfectly smooth. Peace